# Different json format for encode Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I try to prepare data for JSON encode:

```
var i = 0
for (data) in students {
    var variableNewData = ["\(students[i].id)":["timestampValue":"\(students[i].timestampValue)"]]
    variableNewData["updateTime"] = ["updateTime":"\(students[i].timestampValue)"]
    variableNewData["createTime"] = ["createTime":"\(students[i].timestampValue)"]
    i += 1

    let finalParameter = ["class":variableNewData]
    print("LastParameter:",finalParameter)}
}
```

I need data in this format:

```
{"class": {"studentOne": {"timestampValue": "2020-02-04" },"studentTwo ":{ "timestampValue": "2020-02-05" }},"createTime": "2020-03-30","updateTime": "2020-03-30"}
```

but I get this: class, id, timestampValue seems ok, but create and update time are wrong.
thanks for any suggestions.

```
{"class":{"createTime":{"createTime":"2020-03-30"},"studentOne":{"timestampValue":"2020-02-04"},"updateTime":{"createTime":"2020-03-30"}}}
```

Comment: By the way, are you wed to this structure where the keys within this `class` dictionary are keyed by the student id? Including unique identifiers in the keys within `class` makes it harder to create and consume this JSON. A simple array of dictionaries is easier to deal with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s look at your desired format in a “pretty” format:

```
{
    "class": {
        "studentOne": {
            "timestampValue": "2020-02-04"
        },
        "studentTwo ": {
            "timestampValue": "2020-02-05"
        }
    },
    "createTime": "2020-03-30",
    "updateTime": "2020-03-30"
}
```

So, for the key `class`, you have a value that is a subdictionary keyed by the student id, that itself contains yet another a dictionary with a single timestamp. So, I’d build this dictionary associated with `class` first:

```
var studentsDictionary: [String: [String: String]] = [:]
for student in students {
    studentsDictionary[student.id] = ["timestampValue": student.timestampValue]
}
```

You then have `createTime` and `updateTime` that are at the top level, alongside `class` (presumably the data of creation and update of the whole class, not the individual students). Anyway you could build the top level dictionary, like so:

```
let dictionary: [String: Any] = [
    "class": studentsDictionary,
    "updateTime": "2020-02-05",
    "createTime": "2020-02-05"
]
```

Obviously, you’d want to set `updateTime` and `createTime` for timestamp values for the class, but hopefully that illustrates the idea.

And we could then build the JSON representation of all of this with:

```
let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary) // add `option: .prettyPrinted` if you want to see pretty version

//
// if you want to check the above `data`:
//
// let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
// print(string)
//
```

Note, that the `updateTime` and `createTime` are not at the student level, so I’m not sure where you wanted to get those values from.

---

By the way, if you’re interested, a more concise way to build that `studentDictionary` dictionary is with the `Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:)`:

```
let studentsDictionary = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: students.map { student in
    (student.id, ["timestampValue": student.timestampValue])
})
```

Comment: It is possible to do it with encode not serialization?

Comment: You can, but it’s a lot harder. And it is not advised because it opens a can of worms regarding properly formatting JSON (certain characters need to be escaped, others need to be encoded, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the *updateTime* and *createTime* key values as simple strings instead of dictionaries of their own.

```
variableNewData["updateTime"] = "\(students[i].timestampValue)"
variableNewData["createTime"] = "\(students[i].timestampValue)"
```

Comment: I try it but I get
Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type '[String : String]?'